# Excel VBA API crashing

Tags: excel, vba, api, ribbonx

I'm having issues with an API call in VBA. I have a custom ribbon in my workbook. I found code in the internet how to make sure Excel has a handle on the ribbon bar in order to e.g reload the ribbon bar. The problem is normally you can do that like this:

1. I defined a private variable

`Private m_ribbon As Office.IRibbonUI`

2. I store the handle at the ribbon load event

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : RibbonOnLoad
' Inputs : ribbon
' Author :
' Created: 06.01.2018
' Changed:
' Purpose: Callback for customUI.onLoad
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As Office.IRibbonUI)
10        Set m_ribbon = ribbon
          ' Store the custom ribbon UI Id in a static variable.
          ' This is done once during load of UI. I.e. during workbook open.
          ' Store it as well at a save place which survives VBA resets
20        If Not BlnStoreObjRef(m_ribbon) Then Beep: Stop
End Sub
```

The problem is, that if you have a VBA reset the handle is gone and you would have to close and reopen the workbook. So I found a way to store the memory handle in the workbook.

3. Store serialized handle in workbook

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : BlnStoreObjRef
' Inputs : obj
' Author :
' Created: 05.01.2018
' Changed: 19.01.2020 - DF
' Purpose: Serialize and savely store an object reference
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function BlnStoreObjRef(obj As Object) As Boolean
10        BlnStoreObjRef = False

          Dim blnProtection As Boolean
          Dim ws As Worksheet
20        Set ws = Tabelle1
30        blnProtection = BlnProtectWS(ws)

          ' Store into a defined name
40        Range(GC_STR_STORAGENAME).Value = ObjPtr(obj)
50        Call ProtectionHandlerEnd(blnProtection, ws)
60        Set ws = Nothing
          ' Return
70        BlnStoreObjRef = True
End Function
```

Then my code always checks if the m_ribbon is valid, otherwise is restores the handle from the serialized number. Therefore I have this:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (destination As Any, _
    source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#Else
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (destination As Any, source As _
    Any, ByVal length As Long)
#End If

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : GetRibbon
' Inputs : lRibbonPointer
' Author :
' Created: 06.09.2019
' Changed:
' Purpose: get access to ribbon by serial reference
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As LongPtr) As Object
#Else
Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As Long) As Object
#End If

          Dim objRibbon As Object

10        Call CopyMemory(objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer))

20        Set GetRibbon = objRibbon
30        Set objRibbon = Nothing
End Function
```

Now the problem. If the serialized number is not correct the whole Excel application crashes completely. There is no way to debug or log the error. How can I prevent this? Is there maybe a problem with my variable definition? I need to make sure that the code workes on Office 32- and 64-bit.

Edit:
After investigating more I think I know what's the reason for the crash, but I have now fix.
The problem is that in VBA objects are 4 byte variables and LongPtr has 8 bytes. And then with this call: `Call CopyMemory(objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer))` it tries to copy the memory content of 8 bytes to an address with only 4 bytes.

Comment: A VBA reset? I think a better decision is to ask users to restart the application other than handling earthquakes.

Comment: a VBA reset means, if a macro was interrupted. For example an unhandled error. Then all the global variables lose their content.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `On Error goto Handler`?

Comment: I wish I could. But Excel just crashes without any error handling. I tried this already, it would be much easier, but the line `10        Call CopyMemory(objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer))` crashes the excel application, if there is something not correct